# Minecraft: How to I detect if nothing is in an item frame?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know, if it's possible, how I would go about detecting if an item frame has nothing in it. I've looked online a lot and haven't found anything yet. I would say what I've got so far, but I don't really know where to start. I have

> /testfor @e[type=item_frame] {TileX:4,TileY:101,TileZ:37,{id:}}

but I don't know where to go or what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tag all item frames that have an item in them, then test if any don't have that tag:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=item_frame] add HasItem {Item:{}}
/testfor @e[type=item_frame,tag=!HasItem]
```

Comment: Should I out those in command blocks or run them in the command line beforehand?

Comment: You'll need to run both of them whenever you want to do the detection